# Recover webdav from .davfs2

Tags: webdav

I lost my webdav server, but I have pretty much everything in my cache: .davfs2/cache. How can I recover the original filesystem from the cache so I can upload it to a new (more reliable, I hope) server? I haven't found anything about the structure of the cache. I've been afraid to try to mount using webdav for fear of torching the cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lacking documentation, you might need to read [the source](http://cvs.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/davfs2/davfs2/src/cache.c?view=markup).